# Breaking out of a recursive method

Tags: c#

I have the following recursive method that is working, I just can't seem to break out of it:

```
public static void smsMessage(string message, int maxLength)
{ 
  int strPos = 0;

  var spaces = message.ToCharArray()
    .Select((v, x) => new { value = v, index = x })
    .Where(element => !char.IsLetterOrDigit(element.value))
    .Select(element => element.index)
    .ToList();

  for (int i = 0; i < spaces.Count; ++i)
  {
    strPos += spaces[i];

    if (strPos >= maxLength || i == spaces.Count - 1 )
    {
      if (i == spaces.Count-1)
      {
        strPos -= spaces[i];

        returnMessage.Add(message.Substring(0).Trim());

        return;
      }

      strPos -= spaces[i];

      returnMessage.Add(message.Substring(0, spaces[i - 1]).Trim());

      message = message.Remove(0, spaces[i - 1] + 1);

      if (message.Length > 0) // keep processing until done
      {
        smsMessage(message, maxLength);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I hit `if statment (i == space.Count-1)` process the last of the message then hit return, but after that it jumps to the `smsMessage(message, maxLength)` line again and throws an error.  I want to be done processing at this point.  How do I return out of this method?

Thanks.

Comment: why use recursive here- i'd just split the string before hand and loop over the results.

Comment: Goodness what is this code supposed to do?

Comment: @DanielA.White I'm guessing it's probably for a school assignment.

Comment: I have been given a sentence "This is a test" for example.  I need to split this string based on the max number of characters allowed.  So i the max allowed is 5, then the string is split "This" "is a" "test"  where I can't split words in the middle.  So it's not just grabbing the chunks in sets of 5.  So I look for the spaces, add up the indexes until they reach the max (or go over).  Grab all the words up to that point, strip them from the sentence, re-grab the number of spaces, and keep processing until nothing is left.

Comment: This is not a school assignment.  This is code that was started and now I have to finish it.  We have a process that needs to take sentences, break them up and send them (similiar to SMS).  Depending on the recipient, the max number of characters per block varies.

Comment: Where does `returnMessage` come from? Given the example `"This is a test"` what is the expected outcome?

Comment: Return message is a static List<string> returnMessage = new List<string>();  this was placed at the top of the class.  So if the string is "This is a test" and the max value is 5, then I would need "This" "is a" "test" returned and put into the returnMessage list.

Comment: You should explain the intent of the method, i.e. splitting long messages into blocks of 160 chars max at word boundaries?

Comment: @John what would the expected outcome be if the string was `"This is a superduper long message"` and the max length was 4?

Comment: This will fail.  I have to put in the code to check the max length of the longest word to ensure it can be split.  Right now I am just trying to get the sentence chopped up.

Comment: A simple solution could be to add a `static bool EndRecursion` and set it to `true` when you find your answer. Within the recursive function, check for the value and `if (EndRecursion)` then stop processing.

Comment: @John then you should specify what part of the problem you are trying to solve. Or break it up into parts so it can be addressed. If you just want to get the sentence split up use something like `var wordsInMessage = message.Split(' ');` and you'll get a list of words that you can loop through

Comment: I cannot understand why you are calling `ToCharArray` in your query. Can you explain why you are doing this strange thing?

Comment: What is the intended action of your program if called with `("HELLO", 10)` It's action as written today is to do nothing. Is that intentional?

Comment: I have decided to abandon this code.  I have approached my lead and told him this just doesn't seem to be a good way to go.  I am looking to redo this with a split() method as suggested above.  Thanks.

Comment: Oh, yes, this sort of recursion is a poor technique to split up a string. I assumed this was a learning exercise in how to do a recursive method.

Comment: It looks like you started writing the code before you wrote a specification. **Write a detailed specification describing the inputs and outputs of your method**, anticipating problems: what if the message is empty, what if it is "XXXXXX...XXXXX" a thousand times, and so on.  Once you have the specification, *then* write the test cases, and *then* write the code.

Comment: This works for me fine. You will have to analyze some concrete examples of the values you are passing to the function.
This bit trows an exception returnMessage.Add(message.Substring(0, spaces[i - 1]).Trim());

Comment: strPos -= spaces[i];
What do you care about this if your function is returning

Answer (score 8):

Your method is very difficult to understand, and therefore very difficult to get right.

My advice for novices writing recursive methods is to always follow the same pattern until you master it. Start by getting the signature right:

- A recursive method should never mutate global state, and therefore should not be void; it should *return a result*. Your method mutates global state. **Recursive methods that mutate global state are hard to reason about**.
- If it is difficult to express your logic without mutation, *mutate an accumulator that is passed in*, not global state, and return void. Then write a helper method that creates the accumulator.

Now we come to the body of the method.

- Are we in the base case? If yes, return the result.
- We are not in the base case.
- Divide the problem up into n **smaller** problems.  **The difficulty of each subproblem must be smaller than the difficulty of the problem you are solving**.  If this condition is not met then the recursion will not terminate.
- Solve each smaller problem recursively, producing n solutions.
- Combine the solutions together to solve the larger problem.
- Return the solution.

That is, a recursive method properly has only two points where it returns: after the base case, and after the recursive case.

My advice is that you write your program to clearly follow this pattern, and verify that you are in fact solving a smaller problem.

So, start at the beginning: what is the signature of the method?  Let's use the accumulation technique and say:

```
public static List<string> SMSMessage(string message, int maxLength)
{
  var accumulator = new List<string>();
  SMSMessage(accumulator, message, maxlength);
  return accumulator;
}

private static void SMSMessage(
  List<string> accumulator, 
  string message, 
  int maxLength)
{ 
  // IF (BASE CASE) { DO BASE CASE, RETURN }
  // DO RECURSIVE CASE, RETURN
}
```

OK, what's the base case? That is, when are we done without doing any more recursion?

```
  var trimmed = message.Trim();
  if (trimmed.Length <= maxLength)
  {
    if (trimmed.Length != 0)
      accumulator.Add(trimmed);
    return;
  }
```

Super. Now, **what's the recursive case?** You have to *make one or more smaller problems that you can solve recursively.* Can you take it from here?

Comment: Good advice in general, but shouldn't the first advice be "check to see if an iterative solution isn't much easier?" (for C#, if you're writing Scheme or F# that's different). Without guaranteed tail recursion and the JIT generally not being as good with recursive as iterative code, the guidance to me would be to prefer iterative solutions and only use recursive ones if there's a clear advantage. The problem the OP is trying to solve seems to me to be *much* easier to solve iteratively.

Comment: @Voo: Yes indeed; I have given that advice many times both here and on my blog. I assumed incorrectly that this was some sort of exercise in learning recursion; why the original poster would have gone down this path in the first place to solve a line-of-business problem, I don't know; it seems easier to solve by calling String.Split.